What short story from sometime before March 2011 has a husband eventually trapping his abusive wife in a magic painting?
First seen here on TVTropes:
More remembered details are:

A short story [...] dealt with a man who was a painter and was married to a woman who constantly verbally abused him, constantly belittling and insulting him. It ends with it being revealed that he has the power to trap anything he paints into the painting - and he has begun to paint his wife's picture.


The story starts off with the disappearance by painting of the wife's candelabra and crystal bowl which the husband found gaudy and tasteless, and his wife mocks him for painting boring things. She then notices that the items have gone missing and bitches that he lost them.

Besides painting those, he also painted a con man who swindled him, and the noisy motorcycle a punk kid kept riding up and down the street.

The man lives off of money his mother left him. His wife complains that he doesn't make money from his paintings, and derides him for "living off of [his] mother".

The wife has an annoying little lap dog that the man hates. One of the other things the story starts with is the dog yapping to go out. The man lets it out, and the wife yells at him for letting her precious dog out in the rain. The dog catches a cold, and the wife is pissed.

The man reveals to his wife that he painted a picture of her dog. The wife thinks it's adorable and congratulates him on finally painting something she thinks is worthwhile. The man, in a mocking way, suggests that she bring the dog to show the painting. The woman naturally can't find the dog, and thinks that the man got rid of it as a cruel joke.

After the dog goes missing, the wife chases the man into his painting room. He locks himself in, and she screams that he can't hide forever, and will have to face her when he comes out. The man looks over his paintings, where it's officially revealed that everything he paints disappears (or goes in the painting, seeing as everything he paints looks astonishingly realistic). He gets out his paints, and reflects how he'll have to rearrange his gallery to make room for his "beloved [wife's name]".

The wife's might be Edith or Edwina or something along those lines.

Possibly wasn't written by Stephen King or Roald Dahl.


Other than that, it's from before March 2011, but what's the name of the story?
TVTropes's Phantom Zone Picture page didn't help.

Multiple people guessing at it here; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/query.php?parent_id=15212&type=ykts

@Valorum - Thanks! Adding the additional info...
